# How To Override xp.css in Icefaces?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces, icefaces-3

I am using [Icefaces](http://www.icesoft.org/java/projects/ICEfaces/) in my web application. I want to override some styles that are defined in `xp.css`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create your own css file, eg. style.css.
2. Put it into your web pages directory, beside the WEB-INF directory.
3. Reference your css file in the head tag of your xhtml file(s)

You can reference it the following way:

```
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Better using the `<h:outputStylesheet>` tag.